# Web Font Garbled On Mac

Tags: wordpress, webfonts, divi

I have a client website with a seemingly unusual problem.  I am using a custom font in a WordPress/Divi site.  I am on a PC but also use an iPad and iPhone.  The font displays correctly for me on multiple PCs as well as the mentioned Apple devices.  I also checked it on ShotSherpa and GeoPeeker and it shows correctly.

However on both the clients and my boss' MacBooks, in multiple browsers, the font shows but is garbled.  It is showing the correct font but the wrong text.  This is happening site wide, and after site and browser cache purges.

I checked the site and the DB which are both showing UTF-8 encoding.

Any possible ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT: I currently have that font turned off so it wont show on the site right now (except in the header of the Paddleboard page, where I'm testing it)

(Left is client's computer, right is my screenshot)
[image]

Comment: What file type(s) is the font? OTF, TTF, WOFF, WOFF2, SVG?

Comment: I just tested that page. It is a 3MB OTF file, and I would strongly recommend avoiding that. There's no good reason to justify a font of that size, especially when your next largest asset is the hero which weighs in at 333KB. I would recommend either looking for a different font, or seeing if the foundry that you got it from has a smaller web version.